# The Iterator Protocol. Is it Dark Magic?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

So I've been writing iterators for a while, and I thought that I understood them. But I've been struggling with some issues tonight, and the more I play with it, the more confused I become.

I thought that for an iterator you had to implement `__iter__` and `next` (or `__next__`). And that when you first tried to iterate over the iterator the `__iter__` method would be called, and then `next` would be called until an `StopIteration` was raised.

When I run this code though

```
class Iter(object):

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([2, 4, 6])

    def next(self):
        for y in [1, 2, 3]:
            return y

iterable = Iter()
for x in iterable:
    print(x)
```

The output is `2 4 6`. So `__iter__` is being called, but not `next`. That does seem to match with the documentation that I found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). But then that raises a whole bunch more questions in my mind.

Specifically, what's the difference between a container type and iterator if it's not the implementation of `next`? How do I know before hand which way my class is going to be treated? And most importantly, if I want to write a class where my `next` method is called when I use `for x in Iter()`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list is *iterable*, but it is not *an iterator*.  Compare and contrast:

```
>>> type([])
list
>>> type(iter([]))
list_iterator
```

Calling `iter` on a list creates and returns a new iterator object for iterating the contents of that list.

In your object, you just return a list iterator, specifically an iterator over the list `[2, 4, 6]`, so that object knows nothing about yielding elements 1, 2, 3.

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter([2, 4, 6])  # <-- you're returning the list iterator, not your own
```

Here's a more fundamental implementation conforming to the iterator protocol in Python 2, which doesn't confuse matters by relying on list iterators, generators, or anything fancy at all.

```
class Iter(object):

    def __iter__(self):
        self.val = 0
        return self

    def next(self):
        self.val += 1
        if self.val > 3:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.val
```

Comment: I think I'm coming back around. So all iterators are iterables, but not all iterables are iterators. And when I iterate over an iterable, I'm really iterating over whatever its `iter` method returns. Which may by an iterator, or a generator?

Comment: Correct.  All iterators are iterables.  Not all iterables are iterators (for example, lists are iterable but they are not iterators because they don't implement `next`).  Iteration over an object is performed on whatever thing is returned by calling `iter()` on the object.  That *must* return an iterator (generators are a type of iterator).

Comment: Thank you. I think knew all that at the start of the night, but I also thought at the start of the night, but also thought a couple of other things that were very, very wrong.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation you link to, an iterator's `__iter__` method is supposed to return itself. So your iterator isn't really an iterator at all: when `for` invokes `__iter__` to get the iterator, you're giving it `iter([2,4,6])`, but you should be giving it `self`.

(Also, I don't think your `next` method does what you intend: it returns `1` every time it's called, and never raises `StopIteration`. So if you fixed `__iter__`, then your iterator would be an iterator over an infinite stream of ones, rather than over the finite list `[1, 2, 3]`. But that's a side-issue.)

Comment: Yeah, I get that this code is nonsense. The point I was trying to prove to myself is that the object that's getting iterated over is what my `__iter__` method is returning, and that my `next` method is never getting called at all.  Maybe I'm just tired and should go to bed, but I really don't understand how the `next` method ever gets called.

Comment: @GreeTreePython: The `next` method that gets called is the `next` method on the iterator returned by `__iter__`.